# get full value from partial id when scraping using VBA and selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am (trying to) scrape information from an intranet page that has a lot of

```
<div id="CustID_1234567"[...]>
    <div class="logged">2019-09-27</div>
</div>
<div id="CustID_2345678"[...]>
    <div class="logged">2019-09-26</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to collect all the customer IDs in an array for further processing but I am having a hard time to find the correct code using selenium for getting the full id.

I have tried different variants of FindElementsByXPath while looping through the code but I don´t know how to get the ID text

```
    Customers(a)=bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'CustID_')]").Item(a).ID
    Customers(a)=bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'CustID_')]").Item(a).text
```

The first one (.id) ends in an error but the last (.text) one gets the text (duh), "2019-09-27" and "2019-09-26", so I guess I am not all that far from the real solution.

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: you xpath is correct. it should return all the elements. if you are trying to get the fill cust_id then you should try getting the id attribute.. something like this ... Xpath("<>").item(a).getAttribute("id")

Comment: .attribute("id") did the trick "bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'CustID_')]").Item(a).attribute("id")" Thank you. Could I ask you to make it an answer so I can mark it as the right answer?

Comment: Done. glad to help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the "id" attribute from the retrieved element in order to get the full value.

```
bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'CustID_')]").Item(a).attribute("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a faster way (faster than xpath) with correct syntax for adding to array, using css selectors. This is also more accurate as it matches on starts with rather than contains.

```
Dim elem As Object, elems As Object
Set elems = bot.FindElementsByCss("[id^=CustID_]")
For each elem in elems
    Debug.Print elem.Attribute("id")
Next
```

Storing in an array

```
Dim elem As WebElement, elems As WebElements, i As Long, arr()
Set elems = bot.FindElementsByCss("[id^=CustID_]")
ReDim arr(1 To elems.Count)

For Each elem In elems
    i = i + 1
    arr(i) = elem.Attribute("id")
Next
```